# extension Ito integral from simple processes.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am studying the Ito integral from the book Stochastic Analysis for Finance from Geon Ho Choe. However an argument for the Ito integral for non-simple processes is not clear to me.

In his argument he defines $L^2(\Omega) = \left \{ X \ : \ ||X||_2 < \infty \right \}$ with $||X||_2 := \left ( \int_{\Omega}|X|^2d\mathbb{P} \right )^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and claims that this is a norm (I believe this should be a semi-norm) and that the space $L^2(\Omega)$ with this norm is complete.

He then introduces the space of simple processes
$
\mathcal{H}_0^2$ and on this space he introduces the norm (I think this should be a semi-norm as well) $||f||_{\mathcal{H}_0^2} = \mathbb{E}[\int_0^\infty |f(t,\omega)|^2dt]$.

Then he defines the Ito map $I:\mathcal{H}_0^2 \rightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ where $I(f)$ denotes the Ito integral of the simple process. He claims that this map is linear and continuous and because (according to him) the space $L^2(\Omega)$ is complete the domain of $I$ can be extended to $\mathcal{H}^2$ which contains $\mathcal{H}_0^2$ as a dense subset.

My question is, Is it true that $L^2(\Omega)$ with $||.||_2$ is actually a semi-normed space and if so, does the argument for the extension of the domain of $I$ stil hold?

Comment: Why do you think that $|| \cdot ||_2$ is a seminorm? Can you provide $X \neq 0$ such that $||X||_2 = 0$?

Comment: In general measure theory $||.||_2$ on the space $L^2(\Omega)$ as defined in my question is a semi-norm. However if we are considering the quotient space $L^2/N$ with $N = \left \{ X \ | \ X= 0 \ \mu \ \mbox{a.e} \right \}$ then $||.||_2$ is a norm.

Comment: Of course functions that are almost everywhere equal are being identified (so that he really works in the quotient space). This is very standard  in measure theory and I think gets rid of all of your problems with the proof?

Comment: Thanks for your response. That makes sense to me. Thank you very much!